# Bitmap: Failed to acquire strong reference to pixels

Tags: android, bitmap, crash, android-logcat, android-bitmap

I am working on android app where I am collecting images one by one for uploading to server. After collecting 1 or 2 images there is a sudden crash and the Logcat says:

```
A/Bitmap: Failed to acquire strong reference to pixels
```

followed by

```
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 24371
```

Could anyone help me out in getting what exactly the Logcat trace means. I have searched the same but didn't find anything.

Comment: Probably coz of too much memory used ) show your codes )

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs if a [Bitmap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) is rendered after it has been forcibly [recycled](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle()).

Comment: I got the same error message and in my case the problem was really that I was trying to render a bitmap that was recycled before. There was a warning in Logcat before crash: W/Bitmap: Called getWidth() on a recycle()'d bitmap! This is undefined behavior!